# How to use ServiceStack to relay a request to another ServiceStack server

Tags: servicestack

I have a need to relay a request to my ServiceStack server (called server 1) to another ServiceStack server (called server 2).  I am not looking to discuss why I need this, but rather how to solve it technically.
Here is my DTO code in server 1 and server 2:

```
// Jma data
[Route("/jmalist", "GET")]
[Route("/jmalist/{Instrument}/{Interval}/{Session}/{Smooth}/{Phase}", "GET")]
[Route("/jmalist/{Instrument}/{Interval}/{Session}/{Smooth}/{Phase}/{User}", "GET")]
public class JmaSets : IReturn<List<BarSet>>
{
    public string Instrument { get; set; }
    public int Interval { get; set; }
    public string Session { get; set; }
    public double Smooth { get; set; }
    public double Phase { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public DateTime sTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime eTime { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my service code in server 1:

```
public class JmaSetsService : Service
{
    public object Get(JmaSets request)
    {
        List<BarSet> jmaSetList = new List<BarSet>();
        string baseUrl = "http://localhost:1311";
        JsonServiceClient srv = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
        jmaSetList = srv.Get<List<BarSet>>(request); 
        return jmaSetList;
    }
}
```

The intent is to receive a request to the route "/jmalist" which then has the full DTO information in the request, and access server 2 to get the DTO data.  The problem is that there is nowhere to put the route "/jmalist" and passing the "request" does not appear to have the route along with it.  How can I request the same exact DTO as the input to this request but to my server 2 server?

Another way to state this, to make sure this is clear is to think of what happens from a browser or REST client.  I could directly make a DTO recquest to either server 1 or server 2.  Server 2 is the easy case, as it just responds with the data requested.  Server 1 does not have the data, but will fetch it from server 2.  That is the goal with this code.

(I should note that I know how I could Json serialize the fields into a new request URL, but that appears very inefficient and code intensive for no reason.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceStack [C# Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) uses the **best matching route** based on the populated values of the Request DTO when making a `GET` Request, so whilst the Route information is not on the Request DTO instance itself, when sending a Request DTO the Service Clients uses the Route definition with the closest fit which it populates to make the request with.

As the ServiceClients also accept a String URL and you can get HTTP Request Info about the request in your Services with `base.Request`, an alternative is to just pass on the Path Info the request was called with, e.g:

```
var srv = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:1311");
var jmaSetList = srv.Get<List<BarSet>>(base.Request.PathInfo);
```

Comment: I did a slight variation on this:              var jmaSetList = srv.Get<List<BarSet>>(base.Request.Dto);  because I had information in the Dto that I needed for the request, and it worked perfectly!  Thanks!!